# PHP PEAR Validate Package - Fatal error: Class 'Validate' not found

Tags: php, pear

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Validate' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\final_project\validate.php on line 5
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
 <?php
 require_once 'Validate.php';
 foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
 {
 $valid = Validate::string($value);
 }
 ?>
```

I do not understand what I am missing. I installed --alldeps for the validate package, and the PEAR include path is also correct. Validate_CA is not giving me any errors, but it is not properly validating either.

Comment: Try pear install Validate-0.8.3 and post us the pear include path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP parses the [`include_path`](http://php.net/include_path) in order of precedence. This means that when a relative path is passed to [`require()`](http://php.net/require), [`include()`](http://php.net/include), [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen), [`file()`](http://php.net/file), [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) or [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), PHP will start looking in the first directory. If the file is found, it includes it. If not, it will continue to the next and repeats the process.

Consider the following include path:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/php/pear"
```

and the following PHP script:

```
<?php
require('MyFile.php');
```

PHP will look for `MyFile.php` in the following order:

- `./MyFile.php` (Current Directory)
- `/php/includes/MyFile.php`
- `/php/pear/MyFile.php`

---

The reason why you cannot load `Validate.php` is you already have a file called `validate.php` (remember, paths are not case-sensitive on Windows, but are on UNIX) in your current directory. Therefore, PHP includes your file instead of the file corresponding to `PEAR::Validate` since yours is found before PEAR's in the `include_path` order of precedence.

Simply renaming your file to something else than `validate.php` should fix your problem. If it still doesn't work, try echoing the return value of [`get_include_path()`](http://php.net/get_include_path) to make sure it really is set right.